# Update Active Directory mail user attribute from SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, linked-server

Hello Stackoverflow members

I am working in an educational institution and we need to push certain information that this maintained in the MSSQL2008 database for our student management application.

I would like to know if there is a way to use a database trigger to automatically update a user attribute field in Active directory. This would specifically allow us to automatically update email aliases within the directory system as the users update their records.

Is there a way of doing this without writing a complete middleware application rather than a db trigger firing a stored procedure to update Active Directory.

I have seen a few posts regarding getting AD data into SQL server but so far I haven't found any posts going the other way.

Regards

Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am  not sure about SQL commands for that but `xp_cmdshell` commands lets you executes a given windows command string/batch file as an operating-system command shell and returns any output as rows of text.

***So using `xp_cmdshell` you can run a batch file/ windows command through SQL trigger that can update a user attribute field in Active directory.***

Syntax for `xp_cmdshell` is :

```
xp_cmdshell {'command_string'} [, no_output]
```

**Arguments**

```
'command_string'
```

Is the command string to execute at the operating-system command shell. command_string is varchar(8000) or nvarchar(4000), with no default. command_string cannot contain more than one set of double quotation marks. A single pair of quotation marks is necessary if any spaces are present in the file paths or program names referenced by command_string. If you have trouble with embedded spaces, consider using FAT 8.3 file names as a workaround.

```
no_output
```

Is an optional parameter executing the given command_string, and does not return any output to the client.

**Return Code Values**

0 (success) or 1 (failure)

**Result Sets**

**for example,** executing this xp_cmdshell statement returns a directory listing of the current directory.

```
xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe'
```

For details on `xp_cmdshell` refer :[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Hope it helps you to find a way...

Comment: Firstly, thanks to you for taking the time to respond. As AD will be a different server to MSSQL. I was looking for something that might be able to utilize the a "linked server" connection to update AD. I would have though trying to run batch files or command strings across servers has it's own set of issues such as authentication and permissions.

Comment: We will attempt this solution using Powershell, So I have accepted the solution.
Thanks again Pranav